# Error ejecución de Test Automatizados SerenityBDD en Jenkins (Docker Linux)

Tags: linux, selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

Quisiera recibir su ayuda para un error que se está generando en este momento.

Tengo mi proyecto creado con SerenityBDD en intellij windows.

Intento realizar la ejecución de los test en un Jenkins Dockerizado en Linux, pero me genera un error aunque tengo configurado los Drivers para cada SO.

[image: Carpera de todos los Drivers]

Jenkins genera este error, y no se otra manera de parametrizarle al proyecto la ruta donde tengo el driver en el Docker

```html
16:29:54 [Validar Driver Chrome] $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.gradle.GradleInstallation/Gradle_6.3/bin/gradle clean test --tests IngresarCorrectoRunner aggregate
16:29:55 Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
16:30:14 > Task :clearReports
16:30:14 > Task :clean
16:30:16 > Task :compileJava
16:30:16 > Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
16:30:16 > Task :classes
16:30:17 > Task :compileTestJava
16:30:18 > Task :processTestResources
16:30:18 > Task :testClasses
16:30:21 
16:30:21 > Task :test
16:30:21 
16:30:21 co.com.awto.automation.runners.IngresarSistema.IngresarCorrectoRunner > Realizar el ingreso al sistema.Realizar el ingreso con usuario válido FAILED
16:30:21     net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError at WebDriverFacade.java:144
16:30:21         Caused by: net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError at WebDriverFactory.java:158
16:30:21             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at Preconditions.java:585
16:30:22 
16:30:22 1 test completed, 1 failed
16:30:22 
16:30:22 > Task :test FAILED
```

En el proyecto tengo configurados los Drivers Serenity.conf

```js
webdriver {
  driver = chrome
}
//headless.mode = true

drivers {
  windows {
    webdriver.chrome.driver = "src/test/resources/webdriver/windows/chromedriver.exe"
    webdriver.gecko.driver = "src/test/resources/webdriver/windows/geckodriver.exe"
  }
  mac {
    webdriver.chrome.driver = "src/test/resources/webdriver/mac/chromedriver"
    webdriver.gecko.driver = "src/test/resources/webdriver/mac/geckodriver"
  }
  linux {
    webdriver.chrome.driver = "src/test/resources/webdriver/linux/chromedriver"
    webdriver.gecko.driver = "src/test/resources/webdriver/linux/geckodriver"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se debe realizar la configuración de un WebDriver remoto, que pueden levantar sobre el mismo Docker con un puerto:4444 como viene configurado originalmente

Se puede ejecutar el tutorial publicado en:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

Y se realizaría la respectiva configuración en nuestro proyecto

```js
 @Managed(driver = "chrome")
    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    private WebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://ipServer:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```